# Inline textarea filling remaining width

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, inline

I'm trying to make an element editable when the user clicks on it, however I'm having some difficulties placing the new textarea properly.

Here's my work so far:

```js
$.fn.replaceWithPush = function(a) {
    var $a = $(a);

    this.replaceWith($a);
    return $a;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".editable").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  switchToTextArea($(this));
 });
 
 function switchToTextArea(element) {
  var mnxx = element.height();
  var replaced = element.replaceWithPush('<textarea name = "' + element.attr('id') + '" class = "editable" rows = "1" columns = "26">' + $(element).text() + '</textarea>');
  $(replaced).css({"min-height": (mnxx + 20) + "px"}); $(replaced).focus(); $(replaced).parent().addClass('editable');

  $(replaced).focusout(function(){
   
   var data = {id: author };
   data[$(replaced).attr('name')] = $(replaced).val();
   
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: templateDir.concat('/updatedetails.php'),
      data: data

    })
     
   switchBack($(this), element.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());

   return false;
  });
  
  $(replaced).blur(function(){
   switchBack($(this), element.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());
  });
 }
 
 function switchBack(element, previous) {
  var replaced = element.replaceWithPush(previous).text( $(element).val());
  
  $(replaced).click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   switchToTextArea($(this));
  });
  
  $(replaced).parent().removeClass('editable');
 }
});
```

```css
ul textarea {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%; 
  line-height: 1.2em; 
  margin: 0px; 
  text-indent: 0px; 
  border: 1px solid rgba(93, 173, 226, 0);
  -webkit-animation: borderin 0.5s forwards;
  animation: borderin 0.5s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  
  padding: 0.25em;
 }

ul {
  position: relative; 
    border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  
  list-style: none;
 }

ul a.call {
  color: #6ab4e4;
 }
a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

 ul.editable:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -12px;
  top: -12px;
  background-color: #5DADE2;
  content: '\2714';
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 1; }
 }

 @keyframes fadeIn {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 1; }
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <br/>
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "#" class = "call editable" id = "phone">Call this agent at <?php echo get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'LC_Phone', true); ?></a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">michaelnewman@gmail.com</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "#">Michael Newman</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "#">Michael Newman</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "#">Michael Newman</a></li>
    <br/>
   </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/off89dmh/1/

What I tried to do was eliminating the `width: 100%` from textarea's style and fill the remaining width with jQuery, but I want the textarea to fill up all the remaining width with pure CSS.

In my jsFiddle, if you click on 'call this agent at', you'll notice that the textarea gets placed one line below, but I want the textarea to fill all the remaining width, inline with the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, you have both `width` and `padding` set. Please use `border-box` `box-sizing` property:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

And give this property too:

```
width: 90%;
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/off89dmh/3/**

Comment: But this code still places the textarea below the icon and I wanted it inline

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes to your CSS:

- Add `li {display: flex;}`

This will instruct the children of the `li` to use the `flexbox` model which will in turn allow them to fill the remaining space. This should ensure that the `textarea` is displayed next to the icon and take up the remaining space up to the right edge of the parent `li`.

```js
$.fn.replaceWithPush = function(a) {
  var $a = $(a);

  this.replaceWith($a);
  return $a;
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".editable").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switchToTextArea($(this));
  });

  function switchToTextArea(element) {
    var mnxx = element.height();
    var replaced = element.replaceWithPush('<textarea name = "' + element.attr('id') + '" class = "editable" rows = "1" columns = "26">' + $(element).text() + '</textarea>');
    $(replaced).css({
      "min-height": (mnxx + 20) + "px"
    });
    $(replaced).focus();
    $(replaced).parent().addClass('editable');

    $(replaced).focusout(function() {

      var data = {
        id: author
      };
      data[$(replaced).attr('name')] = $(replaced).val();

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: templateDir.concat('/updatedetails.php'),
        data: data

      })

      switchBack($(this), element.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());

      return false;
    });

    $(replaced).blur(function() {
      switchBack($(this), element.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());
    });
  }

  function switchBack(element, previous) {
    var replaced = element.replaceWithPush(previous).text($(element).val());

    $(replaced).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      switchToTextArea($(this));
    });

    $(replaced).parent().removeClass('editable');
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
ul textarea {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(93, 173, 226, 0);
  -webkit-animation: borderin 0.5s forwards;
  animation: borderin 0.5s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
}
ul a.call {
  color: #6ab4e4;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.editable:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -12px;
  top: -12px;
  background-color: #5DADE2;
  content: '\2714';
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <br/>
  <li><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="call editable" id="phone">Call this agent at <?php echo get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'LC_Phone', true); ?></a>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">michaelnewman@gmail.com</a>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Michael Newman</a>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Michael Newman</a>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Michael Newman</a>
  </li>
  <br/>
</ul>
```

`Flexbox` support is pretty good but do note that it will not work with older versions of IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox